# error 'reply' action not found in Controller, but it is present in file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer

Using the mailboxer gem I have the reply action defined in the Conversations controller, however when replying to a message it says the action cannot be found. I get the error `AbstractController::ActionNotFound at /conversations/2/reply The action "reply" could not be found for ConversationsController`

I restarted server the same error is present.

Conversations Controller:

```
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  def index
    @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    end
    end

  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, *message_params(:body, :subject))
    redirect_to conversation
  end

  def trash_folder
    @trash ||= current_user.mailbox.trash.all 
    end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to :conversations
    end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to :conversations
    end

    def empty_trash
      current_user.mailbox.trash.each do |conversation|    conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:deleted => true)
      end
     redirect_to :conversations
    end

  private

  def mailbox
   @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
  end

  def conversation
   @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def conversation_params(*keys)
   fetch_params(:conversation, *keys)
  end

  def message_params(*keys)
   fetch_params(:message, *keys)
  end

  def fetch_params(key, *subkeys)
   params[key].instance_eval do
     case subkeys.size
     when 0 then self
     when 1 then self[subkeys.first]
     else subkeys.map{|k| self[k] }
     end
   end
  end
```

Reply form view:

```
 <%= form_for :message, url: [:reply, conversation] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.submit "Send Message", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Clear Reply Box', type: :reset, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
 <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
 resources :messages do
   member do
     post :new
   end
 end
 resources :conversations do
   member do
     post :reply
     post :trash
     post :untrash
   end
  collection do
     get :trashbin
     post :empty_trash
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an additional `end` at the beginning of your controller, which would prematurely close your class.

```
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  def index
    @conversations ||= current_user.mailbox.inbox.all
    end    <--- superfluous end
    end
```

Comment: Thank you. I moved the extra end to the bottom of the controller.

Comment: So did this fix your problem or not? You accepted the answer, but your comment seems to say otherwise. Can you post the rest of your controller code so we can see why that extra `end` is needed?